# Firestore Timestamp object saved convert to seconds

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue in my Cloud Function. Basically, I have a Timestamp object in each document from Firestore, but I cannot convert it to seconds.

I use the `.seconds` property as I see in the [Timestamp object documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp), but is not working (returns undefined).

```
console.log(postDoc.data().timestamp);
```

Returns:

```
Thu Jan 17 2019 17:10:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

I need the seconds of the Timestamp object from Firestore document.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: That bit of code isn't accessing any property of your timestamp (assuming it's in field `timestamp`).  Could you edit the question to show more detail about what's actually going on here?  BTW the API docs for server-side Firestore is actually here (you're citing the web docs): https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.19.x/Timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try and parse that into a Date object. `var myDate = new Date(postDoc.data().timestamp)`. Once you do that, you should be able to do standard methods such as [`.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), [`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), etc.